# custom phtml not loading from custom layout magento

Tags: magento-1.9

My custom controller is loaded.

I want my phtml file to called from the layout.

I have tried as below:

**\app\etc\modules\Mymodule_Customerpage.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
 <modules>
        <Mymodule_Customerpage>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Mymodule_Customerpage>
 </modules>
</config>
```

**\app\code\community\Mymodule\Customerpage\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <config>
<modules>
    <Mymodule_Customerpage>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Mymodule_Customerpage>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mymodule_customerpage module="Mymodule_Customerpage">
                <file>mymodule_customerpage.xml</file>
            </mymodule_customerpage>
        </updates>
    </layout>    
    <routers>
        <mymodule_customerpage>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mymodule_Customerpage</module>
                <frontName>mymodule_customerpage</frontName>
            </args>
        </mymodule_customerpage>
    </routers>        
</frontend>

<global>
    <helpers>
        <mymodule_customerpage>
            <class>Mymodule_Customerpage_Helper</class>
        </mymodule_customerpage>
    </helpers>        
</global>

</config>
```

**\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\mymodule_customerpage.phtml**

```
<layout>
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink">
            <name>my_module_section</name>
            <path>mymodule_customerpage/index/index</path>
            <label>My Module Link</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>

<mymodule_customerpage_index_index>
    <update handle="customer_account" />
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="core/template" name="mymodule_customerpage_content" template="mymodule_customerpage.phtml"/>            
    </reference>
</mymodule_customerpage_index_index>

<!--  <mymodule_customerpage_recipecreation_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customerpage/customerpage" name="rec_creation" template="addrecipe/createrecipe.phtml"/>            
    </reference>
</mymodule_customerpage_recipecreation_index>  -->


<mymodule_customerpage_recipeCreation_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="rec_creation" template="addrecipe/createrecipe.phtml"/>            
    </reference>
</mymodule_customerpage_recipeCreation_index> 


<!-- <default>
    <reference name="rec_creation_page">
        <block type="core/template" name="rec_creation" template="createrecipe.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default> -->

</layout>
```

**app\design\frontend\base\default\template\mymodule_customerpage.phtml**

```
<?php
<div class="dashboard">
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
    <div class="box-account box-info">
        <div class="box-head">
            <h2><?php echo $this->__('Manage My Recipes') ?></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="page-title">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mymodule_customerpage/recipeCreation/index') ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" autocomplete="off">
        <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add New Recipe') ?>">
            <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add New Recipe') ?></span></span>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

[image]

**app\code\community\Mymodule\Customerpage\controllers\RecipeCreationController.php**

```
class Mymodule_Customerpage_RecipeCreationController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
public function preDispatch()
{
    parent::preDispatch();
    $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
    $loginUrl = Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl();

    if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($this, $loginUrl)) {
        $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
    }
}      
public function indexAction()
{
    echo 'rec cre controller';
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
}
```

here when i click on Add new recipe button...

My controller mymodule_customerpage/recipeCreation/index/ is loading with blank page, which should call my phtml

Have placed phtml both in these locations and tried:

**\app\design\frontend\default\default\template\addrecipe\createrecipe.phtml**

**\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\addrecipe\createrecipe.phtml**

```
<?php
<div>
    <?php echo 'Create'; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried <block type="mymodule_customerpage/recipeCreation_index"  but i get blank page, phtml not calling

Comment: Block file call or not ?

Comment: Im not using any Block class @SH Patel, i just have a controller , layout which should call my phtml

Comment: Then why you have mention in layout file.

Comment: Add your completed module code.

Comment: Have updated the code @S H patel

Comment: Controller code ?

Comment: have added controller code

Comment: any update with the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47979/discussion-between-s-h-patel-and-sachin-s).

Comment: Kindly add all files full code with file path. Include all module files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just little bit Case Sensitive mistake in you code

> mymodule_customerpage_recipe**C**reation_index

To

> mymodule_customerpage_recipe**c**reation_index

Replace below code to in your layout file `mymodule_customerpage.xml`

```
<layout>
<mymodule_customerpage_recipecreation_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="rec_creation" template="createrecipe.phtml"/>            
    </reference>
</mymodule_customerpage_recipecreation_index> 
</layout>
```

Comment: I still blank page here : mymodule_customerpage/recipeCreation/index/ with the above code..also tried moving the phtml inside a folder

Comment: first check in controller,  controller call or not .

Comment: yes its calling indexAction() in my controler

Comment: its was case error in recipecreation ...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Instead of this `<reference name="rec_creation_page">` you try this `<reference name="content">`

`<block type="customerpage/customerpage" name="rec_creation" template="createrecipe.phtml"/>`   change this also

```
<block type="customerpage/customerpage" name="rec_creation" template="foldername/createrecipe.phtml"/>
```

Comment: have updated with content...still i get blank page in the controller path : mymodule_customerpage/recipeCreation/index

Comment: add your full folder path createrecipe.phtml

Comment: template="folderpath/createrecipe.phtml"

Comment: i have createrecipe phtml just inside the template folder

Comment: <block type="customerpage/customerpage" name="rec_creation" template="createrecipe.phtml"/> here you need to add path/filename.phtml template = " foldernam/filename.phtml"

Comment: is it a standard that i need to keep the phtml inside the folder in /template folder ie... /template/customfolder/filename.phtml... i dont think so... i have kept my phtml file inside the template folder , so i called template="createrecipe.phtml"

Comment: No it won't work you need to create one folder then it will call

Comment: i have my phtml here ..app/design/frontend/base/default/template/createrecipe.phtml... do i need to create one folder inside template ?

Comment: Don't add you base create in your theme  .app/design/frontend/theme/template/foldername/createrecipe.pht‌​ml then call in this way <block type="customerpage/customerpage" name="rec_creation" template="foldername/createrecipe.phtml"/> 
 in your xml file

Comment: Check the file permissions.